# Using Vim to edit R-script: why Python keeps complaining

Tags: python, r, windows, vim, macvim

I am very new to R, and should only have two plugins that get loaded specifically for `*.R` scripts: `jalvesaq/Nvim-R` and `vim-pandoc/vim-rmarkdown`. However, I shall see the following error message every time I open an `*.R` file:

### The problem when I open an R-script

- On a MacBook Air (through MacVim): [image]
- On a Windows machine (Gvim):

  [image]

I would need to click on the `Reopen` button for once; and the `Close program` button for twice. Afterwards, the `Nvim-R` plugin runs with no problem.

### Possible solution?

1. Can I possibly get ride of these warnings? And/or, should this be a Vim-Python support problem? When starting the `python-mode` plugin, I get a Windows `R6034` runtime error.
2. I have no trouble using other plug-ins that also calls Python, including: `VOom`, `vim-tex` and

Answer (score 0):

## Partial solution on Windows platforms

- To delete all existing Python and Vim distribution;
- To install a 64-bit Python (my version that worked is Python 2.7.14)
- To install a 64-bit built Gvim (I found it from [Cream](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/files/Vim/8.0.1123/), build Vim 8.0-1123)

### Sanity check

- Open a Vim with the following plug-ins loaded: `Nvim-R`, `klen/python-mode`.
- To open a `*.R` file
- To open a `*.py` file

## Pending solution on Mac OS X

- Also asked a question through the Mac-superuser forum: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302213/how-to-properly-use-macvim-on-os-x-and-to-delete-the-duplicative-app-via-fi